# Desktop Application Load Testing with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing

We have a desktop application (Point Of Sale) which runs on stores which has more than 100+ cashier counters and connected to a local SQL server in the store. We would like to perform Load to determine application performance for various scenarios. I was looking for Visual Studio (2015/2017) based load testing and I don't any helpful documentation. It would be helpful if someone can share load testing procedure for desktop based application using Visual Studio.

JMeter is out of scope for us.

Comment: Microsoft has produced lot sof documentation on load testing. You need to be much more focussed with your question about what you want to do and what you do not understand.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Microsoft docs provide web based load testing and I'm quite familiar with it. But I couldn't find any document related to desktop application load testing using Visual Studio.

Comment: Microsoft has produced lots of documentation on load testing. You need to be much more focussed with your question about what you want to do and what you do not understand.

Comment: There are generations of tools shipped with Visual Studio like Coded UI, and Appium with WinAppDriver. There are also third party solutions.